# AWS Spot Instances and ipcluster plugin

Tags: ipython-parallel, starcluster

Currently what does the [ipcluster plugin](http://star.mit.edu/cluster/docs/latest/plugins/ipython.html) do when AWS shuts down one or more of the [spot instance nodes](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/purchasing-options/spot-instances/)? Is there any mechanism to re-start and then re-add these nodes back to the IPython cluster?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the loadbalance command in order to scale your cluster. If you know you want x nodes at all times, simply launch it with "--max_nodes x --min_nodes x" and it will try to add back the nodes as soon as they go away.

If your nodes go away, it's probably because of the spot price market fluctuations so your might have to wait for it to go below your SPOT_BID value before seeing them appear back.

I use the load balancer a lot with the SGE plugin, but never tried it with ipcluster, so I do not know how well it will behave.